# Как запустить команду для cmd из под java

Tags: java, cmd, компиляция

Как запустить команду или программу в cmd из под Java? Помогите чем можете пожалуйста.
Вот у меня лежит файл Main.java на диске C. Как мне вызвать из под java команду "cd C:\" и после этого "javac Main.java" ? Cкомпилировать его таким образом

Comment: Немного сумбурный вопрос, я правильно понял? вам нужно программой, написаной на java скомпилировать через командную строку файл Main.java?

Comment: можно сказать да. Я хочу программно по нажатию кнопки это сделать. я читал про  Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("команда"), но не получается. Он не компилирует и ошибку не выводит

Comment: покажите код, что и как делали

Comment: Я уже все решил самостоятельно. Я не правильно команду вводил. Не разобрался с синтаксисом.